GitHub Advanced Security for Azure - accessing historical reports
Any idea if GitHub Advanced Security for Azure supports accessing the historical vulnerability reports by date/tag/etc? Currently I'm only able to filter by things like the branch, pipeline, status, etc. But we need a way to get a report of the "state of things" as of certain dates or releases. Any suggestions?


GitHub Advanced Security for AzDevOps provides a suite of security features, including Secret Scanning push protection, Secret Scanning repo scanning, Dependency Scanning, & Code Scanning. However, it does not appear to support accessing historical vulnerability reports by date/tag/etc. The current filtering options are limited to branch, pipeline, status, etc.

Configure GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps


The Alerts API allows you to query based on criteria.ref (branch), criteria.fromDate, and criteria.modifiedSince.
It might be more beneficial to run a "report" on each of those events that you want to track and store off as an artifact.  Check out the csv-report sample -  you can plug into a pipeline and implement this functionality.  Note that you might actually want to report manually after the scans are run and reviewed in case you mark any items as dismissed and want that inventoried in your report.

Thank you, this is very helpful. Will definitely give it a shot.
